# how to print Original request body JSON without any modification in java?

Tags: java, json, api

Normally to print out request body i using ObjectMapper, but this way removing space and printing object to string in one line, example :

if i send request body like this :

```
{
   "Header" : "value"
}
```

and i using objectMapper to print that object

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody)
```

the out put is like this :

```
{"Header":"value"}
```

how to print Original request body without any modification ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can print it in it's original form but you can pretty print it.
With Jackson's Object Mapper, you can do something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(body);
System.out.println(json);
```

or

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);
System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without using any framework.

But you can use the gson for this if you enable the `prettyPrinting` option. Example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();

prettyPrintedString = gson.toJson(requestBody, Object.class);
```